# function not declared simple program

Tags: c++

Hello everyone I am sure someone can help me out I am very new to c++ trying to make this program work. When I get to call my int function from my main function it tells me that it has not been declared. I used a prototype on top so I am not sure why it is hanging up. Also am I missing any syntax?
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int multiFunction(int, int, char);

int main()
{
    int value1, value2, OP, total;

    total = multifunction(value1, value2);
    cout << "Enter a simple math problem I will solve it for you:";
    cin >> value1 >> OP >> value2;                  //gets the three values
    cout << "The answer is: " << total << end       //displays the answer
    return 0;
}

int multiFunction(int A, int B, char OP)
{
    int C;                         //Holds the integer after the operation.
    switch(OP)
    {
    case '+':
        C = A + B;
        break;
    case '-':
        C = A - B;
        break;
    case '*':
        C = A * B;
        break;
    case '/':
        C = A / B;
    }
    return C;

}
```

Comment: Once you fix the function issue, you will need to make `OP` be `char` rather than `int`

Answer (score 5):

You are not passing the third parameter here:

```
 total = multifunction(value1, value2);   //Prototype is int multiFunction(int, int, char);
```

Also `multifunction` is not the same as `multiFunction`.

`int a` and `int A` are 2 unique variables. Similar rules go for methods.

Answer (score 1):

Spell Error:

```
total = multifunction(value1, value2);
```

should be:

```
total = multiFunction(value1, value2, OP);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main function should be:

```
int main()
{
    int value1, value2, total;
    char OP; 

    cout << "Enter a simple math problem I will solve it for you:";

    cin >> value1 >> OP >> value2;                  //gets the three values

    total = multiFunction(value1, value2, OP);
                                       // ^^
    cout << "The answer is: " << total << end       //displays the answer
    return 0;
}
```